# is there a Hive equivalent of the dump function in Oracle?

Tags: hive

In Oracle Land I can do a select to get a hex dump of the column value

```
SELECT COUNTY_NAME, DUMP(COUNTY_NAME, 16)
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
```

Which is expected to yield output like this.

[image]

Hive seems to have an ascii function that is usable

```
SELECT county_name, ascii(county_name)
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
```

That yields something like this.

```
county_name,_c1
KINGS,75
```

But that is only the first byte of the column value.

My question is

**Can you provide some Hive related magic that will show all of the bytes in a column value instead of just one?   Hex is preferred, but decimal is readable too.**

My Google-fu has not be strong enough to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well dang.

hex(county_name) does the trick.